# Add relation to Eloquent Model before create it

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have 2 related Models. They are linked using MorphOne relationship.
First Model is User:

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{
    /**
     * Get all of the owning description models.
     */
    public function description()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

And second one is associated User type, which in our example is Trainer:

```
class Trainer extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get user, which trainer belongs to.
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('App\Models\Users\User', 'description');
    }

    /**
     * Event listeners
     */
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::created(function($item)
        {
            event(new TrainerCreated($item));
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see, I try to use Events for different User types. Inside those Events I want to access associated User Model, like so: `$trainer->user` But I cannot find right order to save those Models.
What I have for now:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = Users\User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'surname' => $data['surname'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
        switch ($data['type'])
        {
            case "trainer":
                $supertype = Users\Trainer::create();
                break;

            default:
                $supertype = Users\Visitor::create();
                break;
        }
        if ($supertype)
        {
            $supertype->user()->save($user);
        }
        return $user;
    }
}
```

Which throw me error, that I `Trying to get property of non-object`
I also try another way, which seems more logical:

```
    switch ($data['type'])
    {
        case "trainer":
            $supertype = new Users\Trainer;
            break;

        default:
            $supertype = new Users\Visitor;
            break;
    }
    if ($supertype)
    {
        $user->description()->associate($supertype);
        $supertype->save();
    }
```

Which throws another error `Class '' not found`.

I tried multiple other ways, like manually setting ids, but they all throw different errors and not associate models properly. Maybe manually set both `description_id` and `description_type` will help, but I don't have id to set at this point.

Comment: Looks like main problem, that Laravel try to request database, when I requesting `$trainer->user` and it leads for error. So `Trainer` Model is saved, `TrainerCreated` is fired and only after it updates `User` Model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found working solution:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = Users\User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'surname' => $data['surname'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
        switch ($data['type'])
        {
            case "trainer":
                $supertype = new Users\Trainer;
                break;

            default:
                $supertype = new Users\Visitor;
                break;
        }
        if ($supertype)
        {
            $supertype->user()->save($user);
            $supertype->save();
            $user->description()->associate($supertype);
            $user->save();
        }
        return $user;
    }
}
```

1. At start need to create `User` Model and save it. `$user = Users\User::create([])`
2. Then we should create `Trainer` Model instance.
   `$supertype = new Users\Trainer;`
3. After need to add `User` Model to MorphOne relationship and only
   after this save `Trainer` Model. This will allow us to use
   `$trainer->user` in `TrainerCreated` Event.
   `$supertype->user()->save($user);` `$supertype->save();`
4. But Model not properly created in database at this point, so we need
   to follow usual steps to do it, as we have both Models saved
   already.
   `$user->description()->associate($supertype);` `$user->save();`

Comment: The `associate()` method is great for creating relationships before saving. My child model contains validation rules that are constructed from properties of the parent model. Until the relationship is formed, I cannot validate the child model. I also don't want to save that child model until it is valid. Creating the association before calling validate (with rules supplied by the child model) like this `$child->parents()->associate($parent);` does the trick. The `rules()` method of the child model can now check `$this->parent->whatever_attribute` when constructing the list of validation rules.